# how to avoid limit of buffer size in java Multicasting?

Tags: java, multicast

in `Multicasting` the `MulticastSocket` receives a `DatagramPacket`:

```
buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
socket.receive(packet);
```

so I must make a byte array with specific length and I don't like that as limits the data size that can be transferred over my network. is there any way in `Multicasting` to avoid this limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The network already limits the transfer size. Buffer sizes in your program are the least of your worries. The generally accepted limit for UDP datagrams on a network you don't entirely control is 534 bytes.

Comment: but if you make a `ServerSocket` to accept incoming connections, and receive and send data via `ObjectInputStream`and`ObjectOutputStream` at least you don't need to make a buffer so that wants to limit the transfer size...true?

Comment: do you think it is reasonable to make a buffer of size 100M to allow the files with maximum size of 100M be transferred over this UDP network?

Comment: @Sohail No, I don't think that. It is not only unreasonable but absolutely impossible. I've already stated that the practical maximum for UDP is 534 bytes, so I don't even know why you're asking about such a ridiculous number as 100M. You don't seem to know much about UDP, or you would know that its absolute maximum packet size within a friendly LAN is 65507 bytes. But stick to 534, or avoid the whole issue and use TCP like everybody else does, and avoid all the other problems you probably don't know about either such as sequencing, missing packets, duplicated packets, pacing, ...

Comment: interesting, I didn't know that. so what is the advantage of UDP? I think it's a really really useless thing. it limits the transfer, it even doesn't guarantee delivery (really can't understand it...!)

Comment: @Soheil These questions are far too broad to answer in a comment or even an answer. If you don't know what UDP is for, don't use it.

Comment: yes, you are true, I found good articles about that on Wikipedia, totally thank you for your advises:)